# Effect of nope card mid attack

Tags: exploding-kittens

Playing exploding kittens and the game is unclear about the effect of nope cards mid attack. If a player has already drawn one of their attack and it's a nope, can they play it? What happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While not explicity stated in the rules, my understanding is that Nope reacts to a card (or pair, or triple) *just played*, in which case once you've drawn the Attack has already resolved and you can't "Nope" it.

Comment: Awesome. This sounds accurate.

Comment: more nuanced follow up for @ConMan, what is your take on when a nope card can be played to stop the 'steal a card' from a player move. Like if im playing advanced version and a player plays 3 of the same cards and says I want your difuse card, I can nope it, but what if the player plays 2 of the same cards, reaches out to steal a card, and has their fingers near where my difuse card is. can i nope then? what about once they have their fingers on my difuse card but havent pulled it. can i nope then?

Comment: nevermind just read the rules it states you can play a nope card "You can play a NOPE CARD at any time before an action has begun" so if a player has already reached out to take a card, their reaching out is the 'begining of the action'